# Detect CTRL+V in Swing App but keep original function

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, key-bindings, ctrl

Wrting a chat application, I want the user to be able to send images out of his/her clipboard. For this, I would like to catch any `CTRL+V`keyboard input. Since pasting text should be possible as by default, the original ctrl+v-function (pasting text) must **not** be overridden.

I see can two approaches, of which none works for me:

1st: Taken from the [official Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html): KEY LISTENER

```
editorPane.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        e.getKeyChar()
        // when I press ctrl+v, ^ this is falsely a white square character, looks like (U+25A1). Plain v without ctrl does work.
        e.getKeyCode()
        // ^ this is falsely 0

        // (e.getModifiersEx() correctly returns InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK)
    }
```

2nd: KEY BINDING

```
InputMap iMap = editorPane.getInputMap(condition);
ActionMap aMap = editorPane.getActionMap();
iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "ctrlV");
aMap.put("ctrlV", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // works, but overrides natural ctrl+v function!
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Note: I am using a "foreign" keyboard layout (German). But I can't see why this should make any difference - I would pretty much like to have my application work internationally.

Cheers

edit. `Alt+SomeKey` however is correctly recognized by the KeyListener

edit2. after changing keyboard layout to US, problem persists.

Comment: Haven't tested, and a long time since I wrote swing code, but one thing would be to try doing aMap.get to get current handler. If that works then your new handler could delegate and perform additional processing. Just an idea...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stick to Keybindings: `KeyListener` is a low-level API, while Keybindings will provide you consistent, predictable and robust behaviour.

The solution here is quite easy. You can simply combine the actions yourself by adding a `CombinedAction` class that will execute the "original" action bound to `CTRL+V` and the "custom" action you want to execute.

See a small example below combining both actions (here my custom action is a Sysout):

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class TestEditorPane {
    private JEditorPane editorPane;

    public static class CombinedAction implements ActionListener {
        private final ActionListener action1;
        private final ActionListener action2;

        public CombinedAction(ActionListener action1, ActionListener action2) {
            super();
            this.action1 = action1;
            this.action2 = action2;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (action1 != null) {
                action1.actionPerformed(e);
            }
            if (action2 != null) {
                action2.actionPerformed(e);
            }
        }

    }

    public TestEditorPane() {
    }

    private void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // JTEXTBOX
        editorPane = new JEditorPane();
        KeyStroke ctrlV = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        final ActionListener ctrlVAction = editorPane.getActionForKeyStroke(ctrlV);
        editorPane.registerKeyboardAction(new CombinedAction(ctrlVAction, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("This is my action on CTRL+V");
            }
        }), ctrlV, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
        // JSCROLLPANE
        JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
        scroll1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.add(scroll1);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestEditorPane test = new TestEditorPane();
                    test.initUI();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your input, it works! Javadoc, however, says that `registerKeyboardAction` is obsolete. Why did you choose not to use `InputMap`? Is it because `getActionForKeyStroke` is only working for `ActionListener`s? So this excact question is the ONLY time when I can't use `Input/OutputMap`-System although Java encourages me to?

Comment: @Blauhirn As far as I remember, `registerKeyboardAction` is only a shortcut to manipulate the ActionMap/InputMap of the component. I am not sure why the Javadoc states that it is obsolete, but modifying my code above to use ActionMap/InputMap instead of this method should be trivial.

Comment: Good thing solutions are always trivial.

Comment: For further research: If anybody is trying to transform this to use AM/IM, you'll have to make `CombinedAction` extend `AbstractAction` instead of implementing `ActionListener`. Got it running now.